# Is possible for a worker to be a coordinator and send to other workers in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, coordinator-pattern

I am a newbie in `Spark` and I have a project where there is a `coordinator` in a `cluster`, that gathers the data from the other `nodes`, do some computations and sends a `global data array` back to the `nodes`.

I am trying to implement this is `Spark` and I created it with the `driver` and `broadcast variables` but i am not sure about the `collect()` in big data.

Is it possible to do this only between `workers`? Something like a `repartition` to one `worker` and send the computation back as input to the `workers`?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - No, Spark does not expose any API for a worker node (executor) to communicate with other workers. There are a few workarounds I can think of (`mapPartitions` + some ZK coordination inside) but that's not what Spark is meant for nor what you asked for.

You **can** obviously repartition your data to just one partition (`repartition(1)`), meaning only one executor, but you have to make sure the data is small enough to fit in one node. You may then send the result back to the driver (`collect`) and broadcast back to the cluster. `collect()` is just as "dangerous" as `repartition(1)` - you have to make sure the data fits in your driver. In this case, you may consider doing the central computation on driver the in the first place, assuming your driver process has sufficient resources.